# Como dar funcionalidad al header del navigation drawer en android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, headers, navigation-drawer

Estaba tratando de cambiar el texto del header del navigation drawer según el usuario seleccionado en una lista alojada en un fragment.

Desde el Main Activity el siguiente código funciona, pero solo se ejecuta una vez (debido al ciclo de vida, supongo). Desde el fragment en cuestión el código da error.

```
val navView: NavigationView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val userSelected = prefs.getString(Constants.USER_SELECTED_PREFS_KEY, "No user selected")

    val headerView = navView.getHeaderView(0)
    val selectedUserTv : TextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.userSelectedName)
    selectedUserTv.text = userSelected
```

Comment: Hola, acostumbra agregar que error se muestra en el LogCat, saludos.

Comment: Hola, debes crear  una interfaz para comunicar tu Fragment con tu Nav Drawer Activity, tal vez te sirva esta pregunta del sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210187/how-to-create-an-interface-to-get-info-from-a-fragment-to-an-android-activity

Comment: @Jorgesys el error era un NullPointerException de la variable navView

Comment: @danms07 gracias, pero como sería en Kotlin?